# How do I save my html/javascript code as a program?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have my code already done for my program, I was just wondering how would I go about saving that program so that it can run on my computer when I click it, instead of running in the coding environment.

Comment: When you say *"run on my computer when I click it"*, I think you mean you want to save it as .HTML file type so that your OS (Windows/Linux/MacOS) launches a browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you've a JS/HTML that you coded. Just save it as .html extension and you can open it with any of your favorite browsers.

Save as => index.html

When you will open the file from explorer it'll open in your default browser or you can also select open with to select your browser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: **Note:** The browser will usually open HTML files on your disk with `file:`. Mind that many features are disabled (like cookies, XHR etc.).